# How can I get record by Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How can I get record by Id? I have the following code to create master detail pages in asp.net core controller, I am able to get all products using the following code and works perfect

Interface

```
public interface IProductService { Task<IList<ProductDTO>> GetProduct(); }
```

Controller Actions

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProducts()
{
    var products = await ProductsService.GetProducts();
    return Json(products);
}
```

But how can I get single record by Id to create a  detail page.I tried this but doesn’t work

```
public IActionResult Detail()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProductsDetail(int id)
{
    var products = await ProductsService.GetProducts.find(id);
    return Json(products);
}
```

GetProductCode

```
public class GetProducts_Action : BaseEFAction<GetProducts_Action_Request, GetProducts_Action_Response>
    {
        public IFileProvider FileProvider { get; }

        public GetProducts_Action(ILogger<GetProducts_Action> logger, DBContext context, ITransactionManager scope, IFileProvider fileProvider) : base(logger, context, scope)
        {
            FileProvider = fileProvider;
        }

        protected override Task<GetProducts_Action_Response> PerformActionAsync(GetProducts_Action_Request request)
        {
            IList<ProductDTO> product;

            using (var file = System.IO.File.OpenText(FileProvider.GetFileInfo("Product.json").PhysicalPath))
            {
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                product = (IList<ProductDTO>)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(IList<ProductDTO>));
            }

            return Task.FromResult(new GetProducts_Action_Response { Products = product });
        }
    }

    public class GetProducts_Action_Request : BaseActionRequest
    {

    }

    public class GetProducts_Action_Response : BaseActionResponse
    {
        public IList<ProductDTO> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your productService have a method to get by Id?  Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: @BryanLewis no it doesn’t have it

Comment: Getting all of the products (using GetProducts() and then filtering in code is going to be very inefficient.  Better to write a new method in your service.  Posting your service code may help.

Comment: @Robert Need more details. What is ProductService? How is it defined?

Comment: That make sense so create GetProducts by Id service then call that? Can you give an example?

Comment: As we have said, seeing you current productService code will help.  Without knowing that implementation, it's hard to suggest something.  If you're using EF, then adding a new GetProductById() method may be simple.  Without knowing your data access layer, it's a black box.

Comment: @BryanLewis here is what i have in   `public interface IProductService {        Task<IList<ProductDTO>> GetProduct();    }`

Comment: The interface doesn't really reveal your implementation details. Can you add the GetProducts() code to your original post?

Comment: @Robert add another member to the interface that allows getting a record by id. Update the implementation with the new member.

Comment: @BryanLewis added GetProduct() Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your data source is actually a file and not a database, you're going to be deserializing that file each time anyway.  That is your performance bottleneck.  So if you want you can just use your existing GetProducts() service method and then filter in the controller (using LINQ).  It's not a super clean way (code-wise), but the performance will basically be the same.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProductsDetail(int id)
{
    // Get all the products and then filter by id
    // change "a.Id" to the actual DTO Id property name if different
    var product = (await ProductsService.GetProducts()).FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
    if (product != null) {
       // If we found something, return that single ProductDTO
       return Json(product);
    } else {
       // Not Found or whatever you want
       return NotFound();
    }
}
```

FirstOrDefault() will return the first object with your desired ID (assuming the ProductDTO property is called Id).  If it doesn't find anything, it will return null, so then you probably want to return a 404 Not Found or something similar.

Comment: Thanks! sorry for late reply how can i display Product Name it in the view? From index on click view detail like i get `localhost:3000/Product/Products/102` but need help displaying data in the detail page